# Loading multiple versions of the same library

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I'm using a library, Zend Framework in this and it has the path

`ZendFramework-1.10.8/library/Zend/`

I load it in index.php

`realpath(CENTRAL_LIBS_PATH . '/ZendFramework-1.10.8/library'), // /Zend left out`

and so can call one of its classes class with `Zend_Form_`

Now to my question, how can I use multiple versions of the same library. I suppose I would load both of the in index.php

```
realpath(CENTRAL_LIBS_PATH . '/ZendFramework-1.10.8/library'),
realpath(CENTRAL_LIBS_PATH . '/ZendFramework-2.0.0/library')
```

but then when I call a class like `Zend_Form`, how do I explicitly tell it to use the one from v1.10.8 or the one from v2.0.0? I remember reading somewhere that if 2 libraries have the same class, the library above is the one called. But how can I switch between the 2 at will? Can it be done in the same project?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use multiple versions of the same library from within the same script?

Comment: Bottom line: it's not entirely impossible, but it's a highway to hell of ugly code.

Comment: Like @Mchi says, it might be do-able, but I would do everything possible to avoid having to do it. It sounds like a nightmare waiting to happen. Like @Mark Baker asked: Why do you want to do it? There might be a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework 2 classes are grouped within namespaces and has its own autoloader that looks through directories (it should be 1:1 relationship between a directory and a namespace).

You will need to register both autoloaders (you may need to rewrite ZF 1.10 to use SPL autoloading so that you can register multiple autoloaders. At that point the autoloaders should handle everything themselves, since there is a distinct difference in how ZF1 will try to load Zend_Form and ZF2 will try to load Zend\Form. I would probably go ahead and modify the ZF1 autoloader to ignore any request that is using true PHP namespaces.

Don't forget, SPL autoloading uses a FIFO method of looking for classes so if you're intending to use mostly ZF2 classes you should register its autoloader first and ZF1 second, as it will give you a decent performance boost.

Comment: While this solution will probably work, I don't recommend doing this. There is such a disconnect between a framework using namespaces and framework not using namespaces that you're going to run into headaches.

Comment: How does this work for other libraries in general, if the library doesn't have an autoloader. I'm trying to understand this in the simplest terms possible. A library that's a bunch of classes in folder hierarchy, and 2 different versions are loaded as I described above. How do I tell my Zend project to load a class from one and not from the other (we're no longer talking about 2 Zend versions, just 2 versions of a library in general)

Comment: You may need to write your own autoloader or some sort of import method that replaces the default loaders. Look at spl_autoload_register in the PHP documentation - this will allow you to have multiple autoload methods that will be called in order. You can create any number of loaders so in theory you could have an autoloader for any framework you want - in practice, however, this becomes a performance problem as every time you try to load a class PHP will iterate through each autoloader you register, trying to locate the appropriate file.